# Replace ALL instances of 'foo' with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to replace all instances of 'foo' with 'foo2' using jQuery.

I've come across the following answer in other threads:

```
$("p").text(function(index, text) {
        return text.replace('foo', 'foo2');
});
```

But that only changes the first instance of foo in any given paragraph:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sj76uh5r/

Comment: check t his https://jsfiddle.net/sj76uh5r/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in reference for `.replace()` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp):

> If you are replacing a value (and not a regular expression), only the first instance of the value will be replaced. To replace all occurrences of a specified value, use the global (g) modifier (see "More Examples" below).

You need to use regeular expression with `g` flag set to replace all occurrences:

```
$("p").text(function(index, text) {
 return text.replace(/foo/g, 'foo2');
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oL6y7080/)**

Comment: Thanks for that. If anyone reading this wants the example for multiple words it would look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/oL6y7080/1/